# How is the performance of reflection APIs such as GetType() and GetTypes()?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, reflection

I use reflection APIs such as GetType() and GetTypes() in .NET/C#.

- In terms of performance, how good or bad are those APIs? I mean, are these APIs take much time that might cause some performance degradation, or are these APIs well designed to ignore performance issues?
- Do normally people caching the results when they use the reflection APIs?

Comment: Good or bad relative to what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't know what "good" and "bad" mean to you.

We don't know if you are using these in critical performance code that is likely to be a bottleneck to your application.

Only you know exactly the paths your code will take when using `Object.GetType` and `Assembly.GetTypes`.

Therefore, only you can profile exactly how meaningful the use of these methods will be on the performance of your application, and how beneficial it will be to try to boost the performance through caching.

I can tell you this: I have never had `Type.GetType` and `Assembly.GetTypes` be a bottleneck in my application, and I don't cache the results (I have, however, needed to cache `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes` but I only came to that conclusion after a profiler told me that it was a significant bottleneck in my application and that caching would substantially improve the performance).

Responding to your edit:

> I mean, are these APIs take much time that might cause some performance degradation, or are these APIs well designed to ignore performance issues?

What alternatives do you have? If you need a reference to `Type` for a given object, or you need all the types in a given assembly, I assure you that `Object.GetType` and `Assembly.GetTypes` are your best choice. The question is, how are you using them? Again, we don't know, and therefore can't tell you what to do. You have to profile your real-world use of these functions and find out if they are causing a bottleneck in your application or not.

Answer (score 4):

They are both extremely well performing and extremely poor performing.  It all depends on your perspective and comparison.

Reflection APIs server a purpose and in most usages of those APIs they will not create a bottleneck.  Use them.

If, after using them heavily, they do happen to create a bottleneck that is shown through profiling, there are options to improve performance.  You can implement caching on your own side, and you can use either runtime or compile time code generation.

Most ORMs use reflection to populate entity objects and since this is something that is done repeatedly in very high volume it can become the performance bottleneck. Some newer micro-orms are using runtime generated classes that can build entities without reflection (using Reflection.Emit).  In our project we use compile-time generated classes to create builders for each entity.  Compile-time generated is easier and has the best performance if it works in your situation.